# how to add an on keyup function with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to add an onkeyup function to an input field that I cannot edit. The field currently looks like this.

```
  <input id="billing_addr_zipname" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" name="billing_addr_zipname">
```

I need to add this ...

```
onkeyup="return AddressCountEdit(this,'spanEditAddress', event)"
```

... to the id using jquery.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You really should try searching google/yahoo/bing before asking something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Basic jQuery:

```
$("#billing_addr_zipname").keyup(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry I am new at this. So how would I handle this part?

Comment: Oops, sorry! this part - return AddressCountEdit(this,'spanEditAddress', event)

Comment: What are you `return`-ing to?